# Python String Comparison - Vowels

Tags: python, string, compare

I'm trying to write a Python function that takes two strings as arguments and returns whether or not they have the same vowels (quantity doesn't matter).

Therefore ('indeed','bed') should return true, but ('indeed','irate') should return false.

I'm stuck with this rather horrifying attempt...

```
def vocalizer(string_a,string_b):
vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
result = ''
result_2 = ''
for character in string_a:
    if character in vowels:
       result = result + character
       for item in string_b:
            if item in vowels:
               result_2 = result_2 + item
               for vowel in result:
                    if vowel not in list(result_2):
                       return False
                    else:
                       if vowel in list(result_2):
                          return True
```

Comment: `Therefore ('indeed','bed') should return true, but ('indeed','irate') should return false. ` could you explain why?

Comment: I don't understand why *('indeed','bed') should return true* because the first has vowels `i` and `e` the other only `e`?

Comment: Wow, my bad. Correction - Therefore ('deed','bed') should return True.

Answer (score 5):

Short and expressive:

```
def keep_only_vowels(s):
    vowels = ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')
    return (c for c in s.lower() if c in vowels)

def vocalizer(s1, s2):
    return set(keep_only_vowels(s1)) == set(keep_only_vowels(s2))
```

Comment: Just `return set(c for c in s.lower() if c in 'aeiou')`

Answer (score 2):

I'd use set intersection to extract the vowels from each string. Like this:

```
all_vowels = set('aeiou')

def vowel_set(s):
    return all_vowels.intersection(s.lower())

def same_vowels(s1, s2):
    return vowel_set(s1) == vowel_set(s2)

print same_vowels('deed', 'bed')
print same_vowels('indeed', 'irate')
print same_vowels('DEAD', 'earnest')
print same_vowels('blue', 'ICE')
```

**output**

```
True
False 
True
False
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks great. However, because we are still learning, our professor wants us to avoid built-in functions as much as possible to hammer in the fundamentals. That's why my attempt is a little long-winded to say the least.

Comment: @newrecruit21: Ah. You should mention information like that in the question. OTOH, it doesn't really hurt to have alternate answers, since the point of Stack Exchange is to create a collection of good questions and good answers, and people in the future who stumble across this question through Google, etc, may not have the same restrictions that you do.

Answer (score 1):

Your own code could be improved very easily, because your general strategy was correct:

```
def vocalizer(string_a,string_b):
    vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
    result = ''
    result_2 = ''
    for character in string_a:
       if character in vowels:
           result += character
    for item in string_b:
        if item in vowels:
            result_2 += item

    result = set(list(result))
    result_2 = set(list(result_2))
    #print("result= {}".format(result))
    #print("result_2= {}".format(result_2))
    if result == result_2:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

When you strip the words of their consonants, you could simply create a list out of the strings and then delete duplicate elements by converting them to sets. Finally you could compare the sets to see if they are equal. For example:

```
>>> vocalizer ('indeed','irate')
result= {'i', 'e'}
result_2= {'i', 'e', 'a'}
False
>>> vocalizer ('indeed','ie')
result= {'i', 'e'}
result_2= {'i', 'e'}
True
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Through re module.

```
>>> def checkvow(x, y):
        return set(i.lower() for i in re.findall(r'(?i)[aeiou]', x)) == set(i.lower() for i in re.findall(r'(?i)[aeiou]', y))

>>> print(checkvow('deed', 'bed'))
True
>>> print(checkvow('indeed', 'irate'))
False
>>> print(checkvow('DEAD', 'earnest'))
True
>>> print(checkvow('blue', 'ICE'))
False
```